# Adjusted Mutual Information

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to calculate the Adjusted Mutual Information(AMI) between two sets of observations using the `scikit learn` package in Python.

The observations are here:

Observations1: https://pastebin.com/eiN88UrL

Observations2: https://pastebin.com/zx9Ath60

I run the following code, I get a negative AMI, which is theoretically not possible. Can you please help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

```
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_mutual_info_score
def amis(x, y):
     return adjusted_mutual_info_score(x, y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The negative output you are getting is correct. While mutual information (MI) cannot be negative, the adjusted mutual information (AMI) *can be negative*. It is also mentioned in the [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score.html#sklearn.metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score):

> The AMI returns a value of 1 when the two partitions are identical (ie perfectly matched). Random partitions (independent labellings) have an expected AMI around 0 on average hence can be negative.